# Making multiple request to different databases fail or succeed

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request, graphql

I am working on a node js graphql api, and I need to make multiple request to multiple databases where any of the request might fail.
I have tried making both request at once and waiting on both requests, but any of the request might fail or succeed, and likewise if I should make the request sequentially, what if the first should succeed and the second fails?
What approach can I take to make both requests either fail or succeed?

`// wait for request to finish
 const [user, recResponse] = await Promise.all([dbRequest, recRequest]);`

Comment: This is not a site where users provide function for each other, but a site where we help each other understand and improve the code we're working on. It would be helpful if you could provide some example of what you've tried so far. You may find this link useful as well: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
That said: have you tried `async` requests or `Promise`s?

Comment: Yes, am waiting on both requests with async await and Promise.all by that's not the problem, the problem is the data in both databases becoming out of sync. Both request will write to the database and anyone of them might fail or succeed. If the first should fail, the second might succeed and we'll have data written to one and not the other and vice versa. Thanks by the way.

Comment: does your code play role of graphQL server or graphQL client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use transactions - rollback both/all when anyone fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all`.  If one promise fails, everything fails.  It does not matter order.

Comment: That's exactly what am using, but what I am thinking is that any of the request might have make changes to the database and the other might fail for whatever reason which will cause things to be out of sync (I might be wrong), please explain!

Comment: actually `Promise.all` is not needed: `const [user, recResponse] = [await dbRequest, await recRequest];` will be both assigned or both not defined(if one of request fails)